# postgresql 10 realizar trigger insert or update

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables, a bus and another bus_tmp, in which I need to update or insert, I need to make a trigger on the bus table. Both tables have the same characters. I am new to postgresql. :(
How could I create the Trigger, if it were? **Perform an update bus get no results.**

Update the table bus

```
UPDATE bus SET (patio_antes, patio_antes) = (SELECT patio_antes, patio_actual FROM bus_tmp
WHERE bus_tmp.interno = bus.interno)
```

> Error = ERROR:  multiple assignments to same column "patio_antes"
> Estado SQL: 42601

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want correct syntax of update or how to write a trigger in Postgresql? also explain what you want to achieve

Comment: You are right, sorry, what I want to achieve is: update the "bus table", via "bus_tmp". I don't know if the syntax will be like this, but the function I'm trying to do: Every change that the "bus_tmp" table undergoes. It must: Insert or update the data that "bus_tmp" has, in the "bus" table. I tried but was unsuccessful :(

Comment: I have added the answer with required trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your question what i understood is you require an `UPSERT` in `bus` table through trigger on `bus_temp`. So you should write a trigger on `after insert or update` event of table `bus_temp` like below:

**Trigger Function**

```
create or replace function bus_update() returns trigger as $$
begin

insert into bus(interno, modelo, tipo, patente, anio, chasis, plazas, carroceria, patio_antes, patio_actual)
values(new.interno, new.modelo, new.tipo, new.patente, new.anio, new.chasis, new.plazas, new.carroceria, new.patio_antes, new.patio_actual)

on conflict (interno)
do update set
modelo=excluded.modelo, 
tipo=excluded.tipo, 
patente=excluded.patente, 
anio=excluded.anio, 
chasis=excluded.chasis, 
plazas=excluded.plazas, 
carroceria=excluded.carroceria, 
patio_antes=excluded.patio_antes, 
patio_actual=excluded.patio_actual;

return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER  
trg_bus_update  
After INSERT OR UPDATE ON 
bus_temp FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE bus_update();
```

Above will do the things you have mentioned in the question.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=17179b7ea94fca58e2891e75bce44b92)

Comment: THANK YOU, BUT THANK YOU VERY MUCH TO THE COMMUNITY. THIS IS WHAT YOU EXPECT, VERY HAPPY THANKS.

Comment: Akhilesh Mishra, can you help me with another question? How can I contact you?

Comment: Ya you can ask here

Comment: Actually, I tried to do this "function" query to do it in this example below, but failed to mimic the function :(

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3eec342c730eebf9058f74c29535ea1c

Comment: Actually, I tried to do this "function" query to do it in this step-by-step example below, but I couldn't mimic the function you perform. :(

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3eec342c730eebf9058f74c29535ea1c

Comment: Please, what I don't know are queries between rows "IF"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
UPDATE bus SET (patio_antes, patio_actual) = (SELECT patio_antes, patio_actual FROM bus_tmp
WHERE bus_tmp.interno = bus.interno);
```

Your current query is attempting to set patio_antes to 2 different columns at one time as it contains SET (**patio_antes, patio_antes**) the same column name.

However if there is no matching bus_tmp.interno for a given bus.interno then both bus.patio_antes and.patio_actual will be set NULL.

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake :( the correct syntax is:

UPDATE bus SET (patio_antes, patio_actual) = (SELECT patio_antes, patio_actual FROM bus_tmp
WHERE bus_tmp.interno = bus.interno)

And the update worked for me, I imagine that the insert must be something similar ...